# Using Pillow (PIL) Library, I am trying to take images from a folder, convert all of them from JPG to PNG but it does not work in the command prompt

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-3.7, sys, python-os

The expected output is → If the folder is there, convert the images from JPG to PNG and save it in that.
If it is not there, make a folder and save it there.

When I run it through the command prompt, it should `print("All done")` according to the number of pictures in the folder that we have the JPGs.

If not I should get an error in that as well. But nothing comes. The error comes only in PyCharm. Please refer the attached screenshot for reference][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0mQy.png)

```
import os
from PIL import Image

ImageFolder = sys.argv[1]
OutputFolder = sys.argv[2]

if not os.path.exists(OutputFolder):
    os.makedirs(OutputFolder)

    for filename in os.listdir(ImageFolder):
        img = Image.open(f'{ImageFolder}{filename}')
        CleanName = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        img.save(f'{OutputFolder}{CleanName}.png', 'png')
        print("all done")
```

That is my code in PyCharm

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.836]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\SharangaF>cd C:\Users\SharangaF\Desktop\Jezon Fernando\004 Tutorials\004 Programming\002 Python\003 Tutorial Practice\005 High level Projects\001 Image Processing

C:\Users\SharangaF\Desktop\Jezon Fernando\004 Tutorials\004 Programming\002 Python\003 Tutorial Practice\005 High level Projects\001 Image Processing>python3 JPGtoPNG.py Pokedex\ New\

C:\Users\SharangaF\Desktop\Jezon Fernando\004 Tutorials\004 Programming\002 Python\003 Tutorial Practice\005 High level Projects\001 Image Processing>
```

This is the commands that I typed in the command prompt.

Comment: By the way, you can do this without needing to write any Python just in your Terminal with **ImageMagick** like this `magick mogrify -path OUTPUTDIRECTORY -format PNG *.jpg`

Comment: @MarkSetchell No, I am supposed to use PIL to Convert a lot of pictures in a folder and save it in new folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*f'{ImageFolder}{filename}'* is joining 2 texts using a '.'

use os.path.join(ImageFolder,filename) instead

and also
replace *f'{OutputFolder}{CleanName}.png'*  with *os.path.join(OutputFolder,CleanName+".png")*

Comment: ```C:\Users\SharangaF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe "C:/Users/SharangaF/Desktop/Jezon Fernando/004 Tutorials/004 Programming/002 Python/003 Tutorial Practice/005 High level Projects/001 Image Processing/JPGtoPNGconverter.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SharangaF/Desktop/Jezon Fernando/004 Tutorials/004 Programming/002 Python/003 Tutorial Practice/005 High level Projects/001 Image Processing/JPGtoPNGconverter.py", line 5, in <module>
    ImageFolder = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: This looks like a different error altogether. Could you post the modified code?

Comment: the problem is with the ```sys.argv[1]``` and ```sys.argv[2]``` It is supposed to be like that cuz in command Prompt I am going to write out ```python3 JPGtoPNG.py Pokedex\ New\```||| ```JPGtoPNG.py``` is ```argv[0]`` then ```Pokedex\ ``` is ```argv[1]`` and finally ```New\``` is ```argv[2]```